# wavering speedometer

Tags: speedometer

The speedometer on my '94 Suzuki Sidekick wavers sometimes.  This seem to happen only when I'm accelerating in about the 40-60 kph range.  I think it may happen consistently under those circumstances; at least, I've not noticed that it wasn't wavering.  When it's wavering, it does so in a range of about 6-10 kph, at a frequency of probably 2-4 times a second.  The frequency and range seem to be pretty constant, I'm just not real sure what they are.

Is this likely to be a symptom of a serious problem?  I have no idea how long the speedometer's been doing this.

Comment: Mine doesn't waver nearly as much, but I've got a similar-ish issue in my '96 Mark VIII.  In that case, the speedometer is also off by about +4 MPH in that speed range.

Answer (score 3):

If the vehicle has a speedometer cable it may be frayed causing the fluctuating of the needle. It's also possible that the speedometer needs to be rebuilt.

Comment: I've seen one case where the cable got loose behin the gauges cluster and was disconnecting/connecting once in a while... Remove cluster and check if it's not frayed as Larry suggested. You can also check the other end of the cable too.